# How to execute jar file in python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, jar

In my project, I have a jar file (which was written by other developer) to copy content from a pdf to text file. Using python multi threading concept, I tried to execute this jar.

After I ran this script, I can able to see the text files are created. but the file size is 0KB. Why the contents are not copied to this file. However I tried running this jar in command line, this works as expected. Can someone tell please provide the solution?

```
from threading import Thread
import os
import sys
import time
import urllib2
from lxml import etree, html
import re
import Queue
import traceback


def createfile(x):
    try:
        file="test_"+str(x)
        print "java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 \"%s\" > \"%s\" "%("C:\\samplefile.pdf",file)
        os.system("java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 \"%s\" > \"%s\" "%("C:\tmp\samplefile.pdf",file))
    except Exception,e:
        print "excet",traceback.format_exc()

def process():
    try:
        result = Queue.Queue()
        threads = [Thread(target=createfile, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,5)]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
    except:
        print "exception",traceback.format_exc()
        pass
    end_time = time.time()
    print "Estimate time", end_time - start_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process()
```

My output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:393)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:101)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:393)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:101)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:393)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:101)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:393)
        at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:101)
Estimate time 1.73799991608
```

Comment: What's the output of the `print` command?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have to backslash those backslashes ? Maybe use a raw string...

Comment: output of print command:    java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 "C:\tmp\sample.pdf" > "test_1" java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 "C:\tmp\sample.pdf" > "test_2" java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 "C:\tmp\sample.pdf"
 > "test_3" java -jar tika-app-1.1.jar -t --encoding=utf8 "C:\tmp\sample.pdf" > "test_4"

Comment: @NaeiKinDus Thanks. it works after giving backslash to backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell the Java application to read this file: `C:    mpsamplefile.pdf` because `\t` is turned into a Tab characters in a Python string. The Java application then sees `C:` without a `/` or `\` after it and assumes this must be a URL (like `http:` or `ftp:`). But when it asks around, no URL protocol handler supports it, hence the exception.

To avoid problems like this one, use `os.path.join()`:

```
inputFile = os.path.join('C:', 'tmp', 'samplefile.pdf')
```

Or use `/` instead of `\`; Java on Windows will convert these delimiters when accessing files.

Comment: Please do mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Don't just add a comment saying "thanks". That's the way Stackoverflow [works](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).